# symbolic link to specific git reference

Tags: git, branch

Say I have a git repository with 2 branches:

- 1.0-integration
- 2.0-integration

I have to work in both branches since we maintain 2 versions of our product.

In the same time, I use this product in other projects, where I'd like to have sources available for completion in my IDE, for example.

Do you know a way to create a 1.0_shortcut directory somewhere in my file system (I'm on linux, and symlinks are available) that would always refers to 1.0-integration branch, and another 2.0_shortcut dir refering to 2.0-integration branch, regardless of the checkouted branch in my master repo?

Note: I've considered using

- **[`git-new-workdir`](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/)**, but files are not *automatically* synchronized (when I commit a file on branch 1.0-integration on my master repo, this file is not available in 1.0_shortcut dir unless I do `git reset --hard` in 1.0_shortcut directory)
- **`git clone --shared`**, but files are not *automatically* synchronized (when I commit a file on branch 1.0-integration on my master repo, this file is not available in 1.0_shortcut dir unless I do `git fetch origin && git checkout origin/1.0-integration` in 1.0_shortcut directory)

---

After more exploration, and with @Michael help, I think there is no magic available for this… Acceptable solutions (for my own needs, some other solutions may feet your needs) are:

- Having one working dir by major branch (1.0*, 2.0*, …) obtained by `git-new-workdir`

  - pros:

    - simple to setup
    - efficient in term of storage (only one repo for blobs)
    - easy access to each major version
  - cons:

    - you have to be conscientious about what you eventually checkout in each working dir (nothing prevent you to checkout 2.2 in 1.0 working dir
    - you cannot reasonably have one working dir per tag
- writing some hooks to create these dirs

  - pros:

    - fully customizable
  - cons:

    - uses a lot of storage
    - fastidious to write

Comment: Why don't you use the separately checked out branches (either with `git-new-workdir` or `git clone --shared`) as your working environment for 1.0-integration and 2.0-integration?  This way no sync would be necessary.  If you don't want this: have you considered using hooks to trigger the sync?

Comment: @Michael I thought about hooks, but in fact, I've simplified the problem since there are not only 2 branches I'd like to sync, but several branches and some tags (that should not move, I recognize ;-) )
By the way, I was suspecting working in several working dirs created with `git-new-workdir` would be the only solution, but when working on the project, I like (and have the habit) to navigate between branches…

Comment: A third option is to use submodules in the other projects.  This has several advantages but you still need to sync manually.

Either way, I don't see any way without several working directories or hooks if you want to avoid any manual action.

Comment: submodules doesn't fit my needs, since I do not include the product inside projects, I only use it as a dependency in my IDE so that it allows code completion